# iPhoneとiPadでの挙動の違いについて（再起動後の位置情報取得）

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, iphone, ios9

30秒毎にサーバーへ端末の位置情報を送信するアプリを作成しています。
アプリが終了されない限り送り続けたく、
電源OFF→ON後もアプリはバックグラウンドに存在する状態であれば
送信し続けたいと考えております。

ただ、下記パターンのOFF方法から復帰（電源ON）時、
iPhone、iPadとで挙動の違いがあるようです。

１．アプリがフォアグラウンド状態で電源OFF（スリープボタン長押し）
２．アプリがバックグラウンド状態で電源OFF
３．アプリがフォアグラウンド状態で強制電源OFF（ホーム＋スリープボタン長押し）
４．アプリがバックグラウンド状態で強制電源OFF

これらを行った後の再起動後、
iPhone、iPad共にバックグラウンドにはアプリが存在し、
iPhoneはサーバーへ位置情報を送信するのですが、
iPadは１の手順以外、バックグラウンドにはアプリは居るものの、
送信されたり、されなかったりします。
考えられる原因や、問題点などご教示いただけないでしょうか。

AppDelegate内では以下を行ってます。
**applicationWillResignActive**
　stopUpdatingLocationでStandard Location Service停止。
　startMonitoringSignificantLocationChangesで基地局ベースに切り替え。
　
**applicationDidEnterBackground**
　stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChangesで停止
　stopUpdatingLocationでStandard Location Service停止。
　startLocationServiceでモニタリング開始
　
**applicationWillTerminate**
　stopUpdatingLocationでStandard Location Service停止。
　startMonitoringSignificantLocationChangesで基地局ベースに切り替え。
　
**willFinishLaunchingWithOptions**
　[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]を行い、
　startMonitoringSignificantLocationChangesを実施。
　[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0f … にて、30秒毎にメソッドを呼び出しています。
　
iPhoneでは、didUpdateLocationsも呼び出され、30秒毎に該当の処理をしてくれます。
　
　
参考サイトとして、
applicationDidEnterBackground、applicationWillTerminate
に関しては下記を参考にし、
http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/tutorial/geolocation-push-notification2.html
applicationWillTerminateが呼ばれていないようにも見えたので（ログを仕込んで確認）、
applicationWillTerminateと同じことをapplicationWillResignActiveで実施してます。

willFinishLaunchingWithOptionsは、
[iOSアプリ終了時の位置情報取得について。SignificantLocationChanges](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7404/)
を参考にしています。

iPhone、iPad共に、OSは9.3.5です。